# Jquery validation on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, button

I have a imagebutton as following :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Send" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/send.gif" OnClientClick="javascript:return checkDataAndConfirmSendToVOA();" AlternateText="Send" />
```

when this button is clicked using my jquery i am looking for a hidden value if it is null I replace the image as follow:

```
 $("input[id$='Send']").click(function(e) {
                        if($("input[id$=imageThumb]").val() == 0)
                          {
                                var errorImage = "../Images/add.png";
                                $('#drop').append('<div class="p" id="'+Id[1]+'_c"><div class="Image"><input name="thumbImage" type="hidden" id="thumbImage" value="' + Title +'" /><img src="'+errorImage+'" title="'+Title+'"/></div><div class="Info"><span class="name"> Name : '+Title+'</span> </div></div><div class="clear"></div>')

                          }
```

now how would I make sure the page doesn't submit if there is error? i.e. the user stay in same page and just show an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return false from within the if statement as so:

```
 $("input[id$='Send']").click(function(e) {
    if($("input[id$=imageThumb]").val() == 0){
        var errorImage = "../Images/add.png";
        $('#drop').append('<div class="p" id="'+Id[1]+'_c"><div class="Image"><input name="thumbImage" type="hidden" id="thumbImage" value="' + Title +'" /><img src="'+errorImage+'" title="'+Title+'"/></div><div class="Info"><span class="name"> Name : '+Title+'</span> </div></div><div class="clear"></div>');

       return false;

    }
 }
```

Comment: I am returning false but still the form goes through...btw i have some javascript validation in the button as well as shown above